# JavaScript Program that Prompts a user to enter name and age and print out the results accordingly

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Write a JavaScript program that prompts a user to enter their year of birth and in turn prints a string in the console stating whether the user is a minor, a youth or an elder.  Anyone below 18 years is a minor, anyone between 18 and 36 years of age is a youth and the rest are elders.

Comment: Why have you added arrays and sorting tags to this question? 
This seems to be a question you are being asked in an online test. Please share your approach so that we can help. Do not seek the answers directly, it will harm your understanding of the topic.

Comment: This is not the correct site for asking people to do your homework.

Comment: My solution is here!

let birth = prompt("Please enter your year of Birth");

          let now = new Date();

          let age = now.getYear() - birth + 1900;

          if(age<18) {

            console.log("Minor");
        }

        else if(age>=18 && age<36) {

            console.log("Youth");
        }

        else { console.log("Elder");
      }

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script to the HTML and try.

```js
    var birth = prompt("Please input your Birth year")
    var now = new Date()
    var age = now.getYear() - birth + 1900

    if(age<18)
        console.log('minor')
    else if(age>=18 && age<36)
        console.log('youth')
    else console.log('elder')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here!

let birth = prompt("Please enter your year of Birth");

```
      let now = new Date();





      let age = now.getYear() - birth + 1900;





      if(age<18) {

        console.log("Minor");
    }





    else if(age>=18 && age<36) {

        console.log("Youth");
    }





    else { console.log("Elder");
  }
```

Comment: I had an issue with my solution and that led me to post the question but forgot to share my solution with error but now, the above solution answers it correctly.